# Why Aren't The Sounds in my Sound Group not working?

Tags: lua, roblox

I was trying to make a music player for my game, however, when I was trying to get my sound to play it refused to work. The games output works before and after the sound, but I can't hear anything. I tried using both a folder and sound group (what I'm using currently) and both did not work. How would I fix this? I presume it has something to do with client-server but I am not sure.

```
 local ss = game:WaitForChild("SoundService")

local rp = game:WaitForChild("ReplicatedStorage")

local list = ss.Music:GetChildren()

rp.SongOn.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)

repeat

    local num = math.random(1, #list)
    print(num)

    local track = list[num]
    local name = track.Name
    print(name)
    plr.PlayerGui.Overhead.Notch.SongTitle.Text = track.Name

    local song = ss.Music:WaitForChild(name)
    print("played")

    wait(track.TimeLength)
    print("waited length")

until

rp.SongOff.OnServerEvent

end)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never play anything. You don't actually reproduce the Sound. To run a Sound, use `Sound:Play()`

https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Sound

Your `repeat until` condition is also wrong. The music will not stop playing once that event is fired, and it will actually not matter at all - when the loop finishes running once, it will compare if literally `rp.SongOff.OnServerEvent` evaluates to true. `OnServerEvent` is the literal event itself, which will be true since it is not `false` or `nil`. So the loop will stop running when it runs once.

Instead, you likely want to make a function that plays the music, and run this function whenever:

- Playing music is requested with the remote
- The playing music naturally ends (https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Sound#Ended)

And then, bind to that stop music remote a function that stops the sound.

Also you should have some more shame, you didn't even try to hide you're making a nazi game

Comment: It's a napoleonic game btw, and I didn't grab the music another dev did. But thanks for the help!